# How to remove Alert Dialogs in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have create a Alert Dialog for OTP Verification after verifying OTP I close it and then I had created a another dialog which is for data processing... and then I close it.

Result:- 
First OTP Dialog closed after OTP verification by calling `Navigator.of(context).pop();` and then second dialog just pops up but It does not closed after calling `Navigator.of(context).pop();`

What I want to do:

1. Close OTP Dialog after verifying OTP (Works)
2. Open Progress dialog (Works)
3. Close it after uploading profile in firebase storage (Does not Works)

Please help me solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgetting `await` somewhere in your code.

Try this,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TextEditingController _otpCtrl = TextEditingController();

  void dispose() {
    _otpCtrl.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _verifyOTP() async {
    final String otp = await _inputOtp();
    String otpValidationError;
    if (otp != null) otpValidationError = await _sendOtpVerifyRequest();
    print(otpValidationError);
  }

  Future<String> _sendOtpVerifyRequest() async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); //TODO: Do post request here
    Navigator.pop(context);
    return null;
  }

  Future<String> _inputOtp() async {
    final flag = await showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Enter OTP"),
          content: TextField(
            controller: _otpCtrl,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "x x x x x x",
            ),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Cancel"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, false);
              },
            ),
            FlatButton(
              child: Text("Confirm"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, true);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
    if (flag == true)
      return _otpCtrl.text;
    else
      return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: _verifyOTP,
          child: Text("Click Here"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```